# Python user input for Def functions, I need to ask for a number and then use that number to either count down or factor up

Tags: python, function, input

I now this isn't right, but I am I on the right path? I am super new to this. Any help is appreciated.  The assignment is to create a script that allows the user to input a number. Then If 1 is entered, a countdown from that number to zero is printed.
If 2 is entered, the factorial of the number is printed.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))
if num<0:
print("please enter number greater than zero");

elif(num==0):
print("Please enter number greater than 0");
else:
select = int(input("Enter 1 to countdown from or enter 2 to get the factorial"))
select = true
  

def factorial():
factorial=1;  
if num<0:
print("Factorial does not defined for negative integer");

elif(num==0):
print("The factorial of 0 is 1");
else:
while(num>0):
factorial=factorial*num
num=num-1
    
print("factorial of the given number is: ")
print(factorial)

def countdown():
countDown = num
while (countDown >= 0):
print(countDown)
countDown = countDown - 1
if countDown == 0:
print("Done!")
break
```

Comment: You should first look into getting your indentation right.

Comment: Click Edit below your post.  Put three backticks (```) or tildes (~~~) above and below code *pasted exactly* from tested code that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right path. Don't use `;` at the end of statements, its not required in python. You can add this condition so as to call the functions based on the user input.

```py
else:
    select = int(input("Enter 1 to countdown from or enter 2 to get the factorial")) 
    if select==1:
        countdown()
    elif select==2:
        factorial()
```

Also, to avoid

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

use `global num` at the begining of your `factorial` function. Good luck!

**UPDATE:** Here is how your entire code should look like

```
def factorial():
    global num
    factorial=1  
    if num<0:
        print("Factorial does not defined for negative integer")
    elif(num==0):
        print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
    else:
        while(num>0):
            factorial=factorial*num
            num=num-1

    print("factorial of the given number is: ")
    print(factorial)

def countdown():
    countDown = num
    while (countDown >= 0):
        print(countDown)
        countDown = countDown - 1
        if countDown == 0:
            print("Done!")
            break

num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))
if num<0:
    print("please enter number greater than zero")

elif(num==0):
    print("Please enter number greater than 0")
else:
    select = int(input("Enter 1 to countdown from or enter 2 to get the factorial")) 
    if select==1:
        countdown()
    elif select==2:
        factorial()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it! It is giving an error that the countdown  and factorial are  not defined.

Comment: @jasminwind Those were some additions that I suggested, that's not the entire code! I have updated the answer, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a lot of help. Thanks!! I appreciate the help.
Here is the final code:

```
def countdown(num):
 countdown_num = num
 print (countdown_num)
 while (countdown_num >= 0):
 print(countdown_num)
 countdown_num = countdown_num - 1
if countdown_num == 0:
    print("Done!")
    break

def factiorial(num):
    factorial_num = 1
    while num>0:
    factorial_num = factorial_num * num
    num = num - 1
     print(factorial_num)

def main():
    num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))
    if num<0:
      print("please enter number greater than zero")
    elif num==0:
      print("Please enter number greater than zero, not zero")
    else:
      select = int(input("Enter 1 to countdown from or enter 2 to get the factorial")) 
      if select==1: 
        countdown(num)
      if select==2:
        factiorial(num)
main()
```